# Magento Bad Format Merchant Id error in Checkout Cart page

Tags: php, magento, paypal, shopping-cart, merchant-account

I recently configured a Magento based site(CE-1.9.2.4) with Paypal with client's Business Paypal account credentials.

Now when I add product to cart and provide the "Estimate Shipping" values in cart page, I get below error:

```
{"http_status_code":400,"http_status_message":"Bad Request","internal_message":"Bad format: merchant.id"}
```

Is this error related to Paypal, but I passed credentials correctly into Magento Admin and it shows no configuration error in there.

Anyone please help me out here.

Comment: is that error returned from an ajax call to paypal or your server?

Comment: I am getting this error in Cart page, as I said, I don't know if Magento already made an ajax call to Paypal just after I enter values in "Estimate Shipping" block, but I am sure this error wasn't there prior to Paypal configuration with Magento.